# How to look up gcc header files in terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I am using macbook. I want to read limits.h & float.h header files in terminal. First of all i am new to Unix so i am not sure where are they installed(which directory)? Where to browse for these header files?

Comment: check out the include path which gcc is using from your `PATH` variable and then something like `cat`?

Comment: I want to read limits.h & float.h header files @BLUEPIXY not prog.c

Comment: run `open -h limits.h`

Comment: @nos thanks it working but i don't see content of limits.h what i expected. All i see is 
#ifndef _TR1_LIMITS_H
#define _TR1_LIMITS_H 1

#include <tr1/climits>

#endif

Comment: I thought limits.h would contain this : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/limits.h.html

Comment: So your limits.h is including another file. Try viewing the `climits` file.

Comment: @StackOverflow32 E.g `#include <limits.h>` write into prog.c